# File permission 755 but PHP file_exists() returns false

Tags: php, file-permissions, file-exists

I have an image file on my hosting.

- FileZilla says its got permission `755 (-rwxr-xr-xr)`

however:

- `file_exists($path)` returns false

possible problem source:

- PHP may read permission wrong for some reason - PHP-manual's example of reading file permissions ( function `fileperms($path)` ) says that the fileperms are `-rwxr-xr-x`

**NOTE!:** The file is accessible from the web browser - if I print the file path as `<img>`'s src image displays just ok... also `is_file($path)` returns true

Any ideas what might cause this problem ? :)

**EDIT1&2:**
BTW: PHP checking path: './subfolder/subfolder2/filename.jpg', browser file address - 'mydomain.com/testfolder/subfolder/subfolder2/filename.jpg' - the main script(which includes another script which is executing the file-exist) is in the 'testfolder' - any problem with that?

Current folder (`getcwd()`) is "/data/web/virtuals/87454/virtual/www/testfolder" 
fopen($path) does NOT return boolean false and also does NOT raise any error

Answer (score 1):

file_exists doesn't check permissions. If it returns false, you are checking wrong path. **Especially** if it's the same as one you are accessing from browser.

Comment: PHP MANUAL for file_exists: "Warning
This function returns FALSE for files inaccessible due to safe mode restrictions. However these files still can be included if they are located in safe_mode_include_dir."

Comment: So? what is safe mode you are talking about?

Comment: From my experience file_exists can return false if the file has no read permission for the script executing the file_exists function

Comment: there is NO magic. if file_exists says there is no file - there is none. as simple as that. check your path. echo getcwd() to see what current dir is.

Comment: Current folder is "/data/web/virtuals/87454/virtual/www/testfolder" - is it OK then ?

Comment: should be ok. try to fopen it and see error message. if it says no such file - then you have to check your premises.

Comment: there is nothing to chat of.

Comment: OK - 
fopen($path) does NOT return boolean false and also does NOT raise any error

Comment: wait. you said `fileperms($path)` opened it all right and returned perms? that's sounds weird. What does is_readable() say?

Comment: Lol it was a TYPO ! (n instead of m in variable x) - should I delete this question? (but thanks I figured it out because of your comments :) )